# Operating system- Time Slice

Tags: operating-system

Suppose a multiprogramming operating system allocated time slices of 10 milliseconds and the machine executed an average of five instructions per nanosecond.

How many instructions could be executed in a single time slice?

please help me, how to do this.

Comment: milliseconds, nanoseconds conversion is confusing me. can you please help me?

Comment: is it 50,000,000 instructions in 10milliseconds?

Comment: Yes, it is. Hopefully the steps taken to find the solution are similar to the 'answer' I just posted.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of question is about cancelling units out after finding the respective ratios.

There are 1,000,000 nanoseconds (ns) per 1 millisecond (ms) so we can write the ratio as `(1,000,000ns / 1ms)`.

There are 5 instructions (ins) per 1 nanosecond (ns) so we can write the ratio as `(5ins / 1ns)`.

We know that the program runs for `10ms`.

Then we can write the equation like so such that the units cancel out:

```
instructions = (10ms) * (1,000,000ns/1ms) * (5ins/1ns)

instructions = (10 * 1,000,000ns)/1 * (5ins/1ns) -- milliseconds cancel

instructions = (10,000,000 * 5ins)/1             -- nanoseconds cancel

instructions = 50,000,000ins                     -- left with instructions
```

We can reason that it is at least the 'right kind' of ratio setup - even if the ratios are wrong or whatnot - because units we are left with instructions, which is matches the type of unit expected in the answer.

In the above I started with the `1,000,000ns/1ms` ratio, but it could also have done `1,000,000,000ns/1,000ms` (= 1 second / 1 second) and ended with the same result.